# Decompile .pdb file C# (Program database)

Tags: c#, decompiling, pdb-files

I want to decompile `.pdb` files so I can see where references are pointing to. The projects are being built from a build server. I also want to explore the possibility of using these to index a codebase.

I cannot seem to find any tools to decompile and view the contents.

I have found this stack post **[Help me to read .pdb file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2040132/help-me-to-read-pdb-file)** but the first recommended example is missing (Producing an `XML` would be ideal) && the second will not build on my machine.

I have also tried using reflector to open the file but does not work.

Can anyone provide insight into how I can deompile a `.pdb` file?

Comment: What software are you trying to hack?

Comment: None, just ordinary C# projects. All projects in the codebase are built on a build server. The `dll`s && `pdb`'s are brought locally to be referenced when developing. @HighCore

Answer (score 4):

You can try using [Mono.Cecil](https://github.com/jbevain/cecil) project. It's open source libraries for decompiling .NET assemblies to IL code. It also allow to work with .pdb files of .NET projects. Mono.Cecil doesn't use reflection, it reads assembly as byte stream.

For decompiling assembly to C# code, you can look to the [ILSpy](http://ilspy.net/) project. It's also open source project and it uses the Mono.Cecil library inside.