# Can't find PDBStr.exe on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, debug-symbols, pdb-files

I am trying to set up GitLink for our debugging symbols but it complains that `'PdbStr is not found on the computer, please install 'Debugging Tools for Windows'` However after installing said debugging tools I simply cannot find PDBStr.exe anywhere. Am I missing something?

Comment: any update? were you able to find pdbstr.exe on your system after installing the Win10 SDK?

Comment: This ended up getting put on the back burner for my current project. I don't remember getting to the bottom of this, no.

Answer (score 4):

After installing the Debugging Tool from [Windows 10 SDK](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/windows-10-sdk), I see the `pdbstr.exe` under `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Debuggers\x64\srcsrv\` (64Bit) and `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Debuggers\x86\srcsrv` (32Bit).

[image]

The script may not be updated to Windows 10.