# Which tool to use to open .pdb (symbol) files?

Tags: windows, debugging, pdb-files

I have `.pdb` file, downloaded from MS symbols server. I need to fetch list of symbols (functions, arguments, anything it has). There is a tool on CodeProject, but it only reports modules. There is `DbgHelp` API, but it only could be attcahed to running process. How can I read `.pdb` file offline?

Comment: PDB (Program DataBase) maps addresses to symbols. It does not contain any symbols, functions, variables, etc.). What are you really trying to achieve?

Comment: I have ``.dll.`` By reading its PE headers I can get list of exported symbols (functions). But PDB may contain information about not exprted functions (and their line numbers of course), their parameters etc. I want to read this information

Comment: Line numbers are meaningless unless you have the source code. And if you do, why do you need to reverse engineer the binary? You can use the [Debug Help Library](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679309.aspx) to read certain information from [Symbol Files](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363368.aspx).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/2040132/67824

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reading a .pdb file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2040132/reading-a-pdb-file)

Answer (score 3):

Good News for anyone still looking,

The information you seek is now open source!

https://github.com/Microsoft/microsoft-pdb

Some real interesting stuff there. Like this [pdbdump.cpp file](https://github.com/Microsoft/microsoft-pdb/blob/master/pdbdump/pdbdump.cpp), 
with its [dumpPublics function](https://github.com/Microsoft/microsoft-pdb/blob/master/pdbdump/pdbdump.cpp#L1290) or its [main flow controls](https://github.com/Microsoft/microsoft-pdb/blob/master/pdbdump/pdbdump.cpp#L541).  [Good documentation too](https://github.com/Microsoft/microsoft-pdb/blob/master/docs/ExternalResources.md)

Answer (score 3):

You can also use Visual Studio's [Dia2Dump](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/debug-interface-access/dia2dump-sample) sample program to dump human-readable output from a PDB file, including its public symbols.

Be sure to build it as a 32-bit application though, or you might run into some problems with it. (See [dia2dump: CoCreateInstance failed - HRESULT = 80040154](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46654548/dia2dump-cocreateinstance-failed-hresult-80040154/50609218#50609218))

Comment: Load the runtime x64 libraries to avoid that. Check the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68559319/2751261