# dia2dump: CoCreateInstance failed - HRESULT = 80040154

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2017

I'm trying to dump the signature of a PDB on Windows 7 x64 using Visual Studio 2017 and its [dia2dump](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b5ke49f5.aspx). I loaded `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\DIA SDK\Samples\DIA2Dump\DIA2Dump.sln`. It built successfully:

```
1>------ Rebuild All started: Project: Dia2Dump, Configuration: Debug x64 ------
1>stdafx.cpp
1>regs.cpp
1>PrintSymbol.cpp
1>dia2dump.cpp
1>Generating Code...
1>Dia2Dump.vcxproj -> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\DIA SDK\Samples\DIA2Dump\x64\Debug\Dia2Dump.exe
1>Dia2Dump.vcxproj -> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\DIA SDK\Samples\DIA2Dump\x64\Debug\Dia2Dump.pdb (Partial PDB)
========== Rebuild All: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

When I run it on the PDB, I get the following error:

```
C:\>"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\DIA SDK\Samples\DIA2Dump\x64\Debug\Dia2Dump.exe" file.pdb
CoCreateInstance failed - HRESULT = 80040154
```

Just in case, I ran the following and it was successful, but dia2dump failed with the same error (also after reboot):

```
regsvr32 "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\VC\msdia100.dll"
```

How do I debug this?

Comment: **x64** Class not registered. you need run regsvr32 with x64 bit *msdia100.dll*

Comment: @RbMm `dumpbin /headers` shows that `msdia100.dll` is `x64`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> x64 Class not registered. you need run `regsvr32` with x64 bit `msdiaXXX.dll`

RbMm posted the correct answer as comment already. But if someone faces the same problem: To register a 64-bit-DLL you need to use the `regsvr32.exe` from the `C:/Windows/SYSWOW64` folder! Microsoft should have named it `regsvr64.exe`...

Answer (score 6):

As of 20 June 2018, what I did was:

```
regsvr32 C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\VC\msdia100.dll
regsvr32 C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\VC\msdia90.dll
regsvr32 C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\DIA SDK\bin\msdia140.dll
```

Then I compiled as `x64`. It worked for me. If `x64` didn't work, you can try `x86`.

Comment: "If x64 didn't work, you can try x86" after upgrade 2017 --> 2019 this helped me

Comment: it works for x64 if you do `C:\Windows\SysWOW64\regsvr32.exe "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\DIA SDK\bin\amd64\msdia140.dll"`, Windows 10 v2004, Microsoft Visual Studio 2019 Community

Answer (score 5):

I managed to get it to work by building Dia2Dump.exe as a 32-bit application. I did this in Visual Studio Community 2017 by opening the solution's project's `properties`, opened the `Configuration Manage...`, then changed the platform for the project to `Win32`.

I rebuilt the project, and now I no longer have `CoCreateInstance failed - HRESULT = 80040154` errors! It works fine with any pdb file I give it.

Answer (score 5):

For Visual Studio 2019 i had to execute:

regsvr32 "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\DIA SDK\bin\msdia140.dll"

regsvr32 "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\DIA SDK\bin\amd64\msdia140.dll"

These files were not found in any of the "Common Files" folders

Comment: I had to run this in an elevator (Administrator) cmd.exe