# Read symbols in WinDBG without exe

Tags: c++, windows, debugging, windbg, pdb-files

I've been using WinDBG to view some structures for an attached C++ exe, e.g

```
dt blah::class::thingy
    +0x000 Flags: Uint4B
    +0x004 Whatever : Ptr64 something
```

But I've been given some older PDB files for an earlier version, and I'd like to view the same structures to compare changes, but I can't load the older PDBs as they don't match the current exe version.

So my question is there anyway to use the `dt` command in WinDBG without first loading/attaching to an exe?  I've seen the DIA SDK, but it seems over my head in terms of complexity for what I need.

I'm not sure if there is anyway to even load a PDB without first loading an exe?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2040132/reading-a-pdb-file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use [.symopt+](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/-symopt--set-symbol-options-) [**SYMOPT_LOAD_ANYTHING**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/symbol-options#symopt-load-anything)

to load an unmatched pdb to a current exe
but be aware and use it with caution

Type information needed for structure recognition wont have much effect .

but source line numbers or Disassembly Address For a Function may not match
and provide bogus information

you can check a module with a pdb using !chksym
if it is mismatched and you don't care about source lines and such stuff but only need typeinfo
you can load the mismatched pdb by using .symopt+ 0x40 and storing the mismatched pdb in pdbsearchpath (cache/curdir/sympath/etc)

```
0:000> !chksym loadany.exe loadany.pdb

loadany.exe
    Timestamp: 5F89E8D1
  SizeOfImage: 4E000
          pdb: C:\Users\XX\Desktop\loadany\loadany.pdb
      pdb sig: 2FDF9552-88E3-4452-9B5D-A03B24165869
          age: 1

loadany.pdb
      pdb sig: CB93F230-0E80-4485-AA6F-42202F1CF233
          age: 1

sig MISMATCH: loadany.pdb and loadany.exe

0:000> !sym noisy
noisy mode - symbol prompts off
0:000> .reload /f loadany.exe
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
DBGHELP: C:\Users\XX\Desktop\loadany\loadany.pdb - mismatched pdb
DBGHELP: Couldn't load mismatched pdb C:\Users\XX\Desktop\loadany\loadany.exe
DBGHELP: loadany - no symbols loaded

0:000> .symopt +0x40
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
Symbol options are 0x800B0367:
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
0:000> .reload /f loadany.exe
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
DBGHELP: C:\Users\XX\Desktop\loadany\loadany.pdb - mismatched pdb
DBGHELP: Loaded mismatched pdb for C:\Users\XX\Desktop\loadany\loadany.exe
DBGHELP: loadany - private symbols & lines
        C:\Users\XX\Desktop\loadany\loadany.pdb - unmatched
```

Comment: Thanks.  I'm not interested in functions at all, I just need to be able to view structs and classes.  So can I just put the old pdb into the symcache and tell it to load it?

Comment: yes you need to store  the mismatched pdb in pdb search path and just do.reload /f  to load a mismatched pdb  i edited the answer with a demo